# Understanding SLDNF-forest

Tags: logic, programming-languages, trees

I am trying to understand this program and the respective forest. This is from the book Logic,Programming and Prolog by Ulf Nilsson.

[image]

[image]

Question:

- In the main tree, why from ←off_gound(a) can you derive ⧠ ?
- In the main tree, why was chosed on(b,a) first instead of on(c,b)?

Could someone please explain this?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Can you give more details on your second question? I don't see where on(b,a) is chosen in the main tree. I'm assuming the main tree is the big one on the left hand side of the figure?

Comment: @SimonJ Yes, the main tree is the big one on the left hand side of the figure. on(b,a) is choosen right after the branch splits to be now two branch

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question: SLDNF resolution employs *negation as failure* to deal with negation.

So from ←$\neg$off_ground(a) we derive ⧠ by trying to derive ←off_ground(a) and failing (i.e. deriving **FF**). 
This is done in the upper tree on the right hand side.

Comment: Will it always be that way right?, I mean if you have **FF** in a subtree then in the main tree should be ⧠ ?